# Setting message signature of outgoing message using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, signature, macos-sierra, apple-mail

Since I installed Sierra I can't get a piece of AppleScript working which worked before.

I'm trying to create a message (in Apple Mail) with a signature, but keep getting errors.

I used to create/fill the message like this:

```
set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {content:messageContent}
set message signature of msg to signature "X"
```

Before Sierra this worked perfect, now I'm getting an error saying: `Mail got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.`

So I tried several things and ended up (using AppleScript dictionaries) with:

```
set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {content:messageContent, message signature:signature "X"}
```

Which ends up in an error saying: `Mail got an error: Can’t make class outgoing message.`

Anyone who can help me out on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug. I had the same issue.

You also failed to mention that this is for Mail in your original reply. Might want to include the application in future posts!

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answer.

I updated my question mentioning Apple Mail, thank you for point this out.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and came across a working solution. The "button 3" used to be "button 2" until I upgraded to Sierra 10.12.4 this past weekend.

Keystroke "F", is just the first letter of my signature name. Modify that as you wish.

```
try
    set message signature of theMessage to signature "your signature name"

on error

    tell application "Mail" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Mail"
            click pop up button 3 of window 1
            delay 0.01
            keystroke "F"
            delay 0.01
            keystroke return
            delay 0.01
        end tell
    end tell

end try
```